# Overlapping faces in imported .obj file

Tags: mesh, vertices, topology, geometry

[image]

I've imported a model I made in Zephyr, and the model looks quite nice, except for these strange overlapping vertices/faces all over the place.

Looks like blender just doesn't know what to do about irregularities in the model.  is there any easy way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this to a smaller degree with Qlone today. The best I know:

1. Select all, and Merge By Distance.
2. Degenerate Dissolve
3. Vertex -> Smooth Vertices (will change things!) adjust the strength of the effect as needed.